# Magento2: broken layout after installing extension

Tags: magento2, extensions, frontend

I installed a 3rd party extension on Magento2 and followed these instructions: 
https://store.orange35.com/media/wysiwyg/guides/Image-Constructor-For-Custom-Options-for-Magento2-Installation-Guide.pdf

The frontend layout is now broken, as if CSS was missing... Even after disabling the extension with

```
 php -f bin/magento module:disable Orange35_ImageConstructor
```

The layout is still broken. How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are on `developer` mode you need to run the commands for compilation ( symlinks ) `grunt exec:your_theme grunt less:your_theme grunt watch` if in production mode,

- bin/magento setup:upgrade
- bin/magento setup:di:compile
- bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy **lang_code**
- bin/magento index:reindex
- bin/magento cache:clean